# What do you call the entire first part of a URL?

Tags: url, terminology, uri

If I have a URL like:

```
http://www.example.com:9090/test.html
```

Then I know that `www.example.com` is the host name, but what do you call `http://www.example.com:9090`? Is there some kind of established name for that?

Comment: I like the [picture in this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/42845/5312) visualizing the different parts.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't know the name for when it has the scheme, but the hostname with the port is collectively known as the *`Authority`*. A nice explanation [`here`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Example_URIs).

Comment: Actually, it would be the "scheme and authority" according to that link.

Answer (score 106):

It is called the **origin**.

---

More generally speaking, here are the different parts of a URL, as per [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location). (So at least according to how Javascript calls it)

```
protocol://username:password@hostname:port/pathname?search#hash
-----------------------------href------------------------------
                             -----host----
-----------      origin      -------------
```

- `protocol` - protocol scheme of the URL, including the final ':'
- `hostname` - domain name
- `port` - port number
- `pathname` - *`/pathname`*
- `search` - *`?parameters`*
- `hash` - *`#fragment_identifier`*
- `username` - username specified before the domain name
- `password` - password specified before the domain name
- `href` - the entire URL
- `origin` - `protocol://hostname:port`
- `host` - `hostname:port`

Note that the exact naming of each part may be different in different standards. For example, 'host' in [RFC 6454 section 4.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-4) means 'hostname' in the above diagram.

Comment: Origin seems very specific to browser context. Is this term used wider? Are there more references?

Comment: A URI is just a string, from reading all these answers, I get the feeling that different use cases will have different names. I got the names for this answer from `window.location`, so those are the names for the 'browser context'. See the other answers for other uses.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty kind stranger :p

Comment: what do you call everything *after* the origin?

Comment: Not sure there's a name for it, but this should be a different question anyways :p

Comment: @Jonah good one, do ask a question, I guess `path, query and fragment` is explicit and correct, albeit not concise.

Comment: So no name for the whole *URL* minus the 'test.html'? Ironic really, since this would be a really handy term!

Comment: @CodeCabbie That's called the *origin*

Comment: I check your source and RFC 6454 refers particularly to `origin`. What is the standard or RFC for the whole URL? Is therey any?

Comment: The RFC you linked directly contradicts your definition of `host`. It does not include the port in the host, but rather as a separate component.

Answer (score 30):

- http:// - Protocol
- www - Server-Name (subdomain)
- example - Second Level Domain (SLD)
- com - Top Level Domain (TLD)
- 9090 - Port number
- /test.html - Path

Save the protocol, you can refer to 'www.example.com' as either the hostname or - more specifically - the 'fully qualified domain name'.

Toss in the '9090' and personally I'd be comfortable calling it the host, as that's usually what you'd get as the 'host' header in an HTTP request; something like 'host: [www.example.com:9090'](http://www.example.com:9090%27). In PHP it would be stored in the `$_SERVER` variable under 'HTTP_HOST' or 'SERVER_NAME'. In JavaScript it would be available as the `document.location.host`.

I don't know, what you could call it once you toss in 'http://' :(

Comment: Thanks Richard, this was helpful. For a more complete list see http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-glossary-url-definitions/

Answer (score 15):

RFC 3986 details the [syntax components](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3). The part you refer to would be the *scheme* (`http`) and *authority* (`www.example.com:9090`).

Comment: how do we merge this terminology with the one given in `windows.location`? I'm confused! Shall we. for example, call it `protocol` or `scheme`?

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, the .Net framework Uri class goes for "GetLeftPart()". 
It's irritating not having a proper name for "scheme + authority"

Comment: this is hilarious

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. If there was, I would expect the DOM to reflect this in the window.location class: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location

Answer (score -2):

You can read about every part of URL on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url#Syntax).
You'll find there that `http` is a protocol name, `:9090` determines that the connection should be establishment on port #9090 etc.

Answer (score -3):

It means that the HTTP server hosting example.com is using the port `9090` for processing HTTP requests, it is a directive to the browser that it should connect to that server on port 9090 instead of 80 which it normally does if the port is not specified

Comment: That's not what @jnicklas asked, I'm sure he knows what port is and how to change it. He wants to know how to name that exact part of URI (to store it in database under that name probably)