# What do we call the combined path, query, and fragment in a URI?

Tags: uri, terminology

A URI is composed of several parts: `scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]`.  Often, I find myself wanting to refer to the entire part of the URI to the right of the host and port - the part that would be considered the URI in an HTTP request:

```
GET /path?query#fragment
Host: example.com
```

As a short-hand, I normally call this the "path", but that's not quite accurate, as the path is only part of it.  This is essentially the inverse of [What do you call the entire first part of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081645/120999)

Is there an agreed-upon name for this?

Answer (score 5):

Within a full HTTP URI, there doesn’t seem to be a term that denotes everything coming after the *authority*.

If you only have the part in question as a URI reference (e.g., in a HTTP GET request), it’s called a [***relative reference***](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2):

> ```
> relative-ref  = relative-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
> ```

But this term also includes *network-path references* (often called [protocol-relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol-relative) URIs), e.g. `//example.com/path?query#fragment`. To exclude this case, you could use the terms for the other two cases:

- ***absolute-path reference*** (begins with a single `/`, e.g. `/path?query#fragment`)
- ***relative-path reference*** (doesn’t begin with a `/`, e.g., `path?query#fragment`)¹

---

¹ If the first path segment contains a `:`, you have to begin the relative-path reference with `./` (e.g., `./pa:th?query#fragment`).

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) says:

request-line = method SP **request-target** SP HTTP-version CRLF

I personally prefer to use the terms

- *origin* for scheme and authority (where) and
- *resource* for path, query string and fragment (what).

Comment: `request-target =  origin-form / absolute-form / authority-form / asterisk-form`, so it may be the absolute URL

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any term for that portion of a URI.

[RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) says this

```
     foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
     \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
      |           |            |            |        |
   scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
      |   _____________________|__
     / \ /                        \
     urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```