# Naming convention for the combination of a URL's path & query

Tags: url, uri, naming-conventions, semantics

I'm struggling with a naming convention for a specific part of a URL.
For example: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?abcd`

Conventionally, this is what follows:
`path` = `/questions/ask`
`query string` = `abcd`

However I'm storing the following in a database, and am struggling on what to call it (it's not really a URI, path):
`/questions/ask?abcd`

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: Question that asks for a term which also includes the fragment: [What do we call the combined path, query, and fragment in a URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47543432/1591669)

Comment: Thanks for the link; happy to know other people are struggling with this as well :)