# Labels for the different parts of the URL "https://www.gooogle:com@home.html"

Tags: url, terminology

I have a question on the labeling of parts of a URL and would like to clarify my understanding.

```
https://www.gooogle:com@home.html
```

What I have:

```
https       - protocol/scheme  
www         - sub-domain (?)  
google      - username   
www.gooogle - query string  
google.com  - domain  
home.html   - file  
com         - top level domain  
home        - query string (?)  
html        - fragment (I don't think so?)   
home.html   - file
```

I've referred to this post [What do you call the entire first part of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081645/what-do-you-call-the-entire-first-part-of-a-url) and other resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the terminology of the [current URI standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986):

- `https` is the [**scheme**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1) component.
- `www.gooogle:com@home.html` is the [**authority**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2) component.
- `www.gooogle:com` is the [**userinfo**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1) subcomponent (where "www.gooogle" could be the username, and "com" could be the password).
- `home.html` is the [**host**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) subcomponent (where "home" could be the second-level domain, and "html" could be the top-level domain).
- (The [port](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.3) subcomponent is empty.)
- (The [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) component is empty.)
- (The [query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) component doesn’t exist.)
- (The [fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5) component doesn’t exist.)

A URL similar to this is often used for [phishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing#Link_manipulation) attempts, in the hope that users get the impression the link leads to the domain google.com instead of the domain home.html. But for such malicious cases, the URL would probably be `https://www.google.com@home.html` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Every domain, in this case (google), as a registry operator which in this case is the ".com".

```
              host          path       fragment 
          ┌────┴────────┐ ┌───┴───┐     ┌─┴┐
  https://www.gooogle.com@home.html?id=1#asc
  └─┬─┘ └───────┬──────────────────┘└─┬┘ 
protocol    authority               query
```